# Live graphing in dash

Tags: python, pandas, plotly-dash

Noob alert, I want to create 3 graphs in Dash with some data in it. So I have a data.csv file which is updating every hour and storing data in it:

```
2021-01-01 18:07:09|15547|45.03|742031.4|2935|30.7|112045.75|5815|45.0|314413.09|1835|28.8|75511.78
2021-01-01 19:25:57|13995|44.03|660573.87|3046|27.0|114017.46|5024|37.84|256953.02|1911|27.8|77646.2
2021-01-01 20:25:59|13710|44.03|647995.57|3180|25.0|117480.46|5349|30.0|269511.82|1672|28.8|70775.0
2021-01-01 21:25:59|13710|44.03|647995.57|3180|25.0|117480.46|5349|30.0|269511.82|1672|28.8|70775.0
2021-01-01 22:26:00|13863|43.99|637484.0|3613|28.9|134806.24|5316|38.97|245546.28|2100|28.75|96306.19
2021-01-01 23:25:59|14769|42.99|676265.94|3570|28.55|133435.66|4336|38.97|206593.23|2292|28.75|101826.19
2021-01-02 00:25:59|13945|42.99|640842.18|3601|28.5|134301.16|3843|35.99|186926.98|2072|28.75|95096.52
```

with this code:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd


DATA_FILE = "data.csv"

app = dash.Dash()


data = pd.read_csv(
    DATA_FILE,
    names=[
        "date",
        "columnOneData",
        "columnTwoData",
        "columnThreeData",
        "columnFourData",
        "columnFiveData",
        "columnSixData",
        "columnSevenData",
        "columnEightData",
        "columnNineData",
        "columnTenData",
        "columnElevData",
        "columnTwelData",
    ],
    sep="|",
)
date = data.date.tolist()

columnOneData = data.columnOneData.tolist()
columnTwoData = data.columnTwoData.tolist()
columnThreeData = data.columnThreeData.tolist()

columnFourData = data.columnFourData.tolist()
columnFiveData = data.columnFiveData.tolist()
columnSixData = data.columnSixData.tolist()

columnSevenData = data.columnSevenData.tolist()
columnEightData = data.columnEightData.tolist()
columnNineData = data.columnNineData.tolist()

columnTenData = data.columnTenData.tolist()
columnElevData = data.columnElevData.tolist()
columnTwelData = data.columnTwelData.tolist()


app.layout = html.Div(
    children=[
        html.H1(children="Total numbers"),
        dcc.Graph(
            id="count",
            figure={
                "data": [
                    {
                        "x": date,
                        "y": columnOneData,
                        "type": "line",
                        "name": "ColOneData",
                    },
                    {
                        "x": date,
                        "y": columnFourData,
                        "type": "line",
                        "name": "ColFourData",
                    },
                    {
                        "x": date,
                        "y": columnSevenData,
                        "type": "line",
                        "name": "ColSevenData",
                    },
                    {
                        "x": date,
                        "y": columnTenData,
                        "type": "line",
                        "name": "ColTenData",
                    },
                ],
            },
        ),
        html.H1(children="Lowest price"),
        dcc.Graph(
            id="minprice",
            figure={
                "data": [
                    {
                        "x": date,
                        "y": columnTwoData,
                        "type": "line",
                        "name": "ColTwoData",
                    },
                    {
                        "x": date,
                        "y": columnFiveData,
                        "type": "line",
                        "name": "ColFiveData",
                    },
                    {
                        "x": date,
                        "y": columnEightData,
                        "type": "line",
                        "name": "ColEightData",
                    },
                    {
                        "x": date,
                        "y": columnElevData,
                        "type": "line",
                        "name": "ColElevData",
                    },
                ],
            },
        ),
        html.H1(children="BuyOut"),
        dcc.Graph(
            id="buyout",
            figure={
                "data": [
                    {
                        "x": date,
                        "y": columnThreeData,
                        "type": "line",
                        "name": "ColThreeData",
                    },
                    {
                        "x": date,
                        "y": columnSixData,
                        "type": "line",
                        "name": "ColSixData",
                    },
                    {
                        "x": date,
                        "y": columnNineData,
                        "type": "line",
                        "name": "ColNineData",
                    },
                    {
                        "x": date,
                        "y": columnTwelData,
                        "type": "line",
                        "name": "ColTwelData",
                    },
                ],
            },
        ),
    ]
)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

I managed to create the graph I was looking for but obviously by the code - it's not updating when new data comes in or mainly when I **refresh** the page. I'm pretty new to Dash and I heard about callbacks and watches some videos but I actually wasn't able to reproduce the same updating code to my case. I'm looking for a little bit of help by showing multiple multiline graph example or some kind of example that I can use. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [Dash Interval Component](https://dash.plotly.com/live-updates), designed to do just that. Here's a small example that refreshes `data.csv`. Just run this and change the `.csv` file (which should have two columns for the x and y coordinates.

```
import dash
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html


app = dash.Dash(__name__)

def _create_fig():
    df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
    df.columns=['x','y']
    return go.Figure(
        data=go.Scatter(
            x=df['x'],
            y=df['y']))


app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(
        id='g1',
        figure=_create_fig()),
    dcc.Interval(
        id='interval-component',
        interval=1*1000, # in milliseconds
        n_intervals=0
    )
])


@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('g1', 'figure'),
    dash.dependencies.Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals'))
def refresh_data(n_clicks):
    return _create_fig()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True, port=8080)
```

Dumb data for `data.csv`

```
1,2
3,4
5,6
```

and the file to replace it

```
11,2
3,44
55,6
```

From the same page, you see that you could also just update the data on refresh by setting `app.layout` to a function instance that defines the layout. This would obviate the need for a callback function or the use of an Interval component:

```
import dash
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html


app = dash.Dash(__name__)

def _create_fig():
    df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
    df.columns=['x','y']
    return go.Figure(
        data=go.Scatter(
            x=df['x'],
            y=df['y']))

def serve_layout():
    return html.Div([
        dcc.Graph(
            figure=_create_fig()),
    ])

app.layout = serve_layout


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True, port=8080)
```

Comment: I kinda didn't need the interval component and with the app.layout you hit the jackpot. That was exactly what I was looking for and now after few modifications I can finally go to sleep. :D Thank you!